# Accessing IIS relevant Registry values with C# on a Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, .net, iis, registry

I want to read for some reasons specific IIS relevant values from the registry (with C#) of a **Windows Server 2008**. I need the **version number** of the installed IIS and if the IIS  has the **IIS6-Compatibility** mode enabled.

I know that **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\"MajorVersion"** and **"MinorVersion"** gives me the IIS Version
and **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components\"WMICompatibility"** gives me the information if the IIS6-Compatibility mode is enabled or not.

The problem is now, I cannot access/read the values in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\InetStp\Components.
**Registry.GetValue** returns null. The problem is, that on one server it works, on another server it doesn't work.

So what could be the problem? What are the preconditions and what I have to configure to ensure, that I can read all these values?

Comment: Are you trying to read these values from an ASP.NET application? If so, are the trust levels set the same on both servers?